# Custom UITableViewCell not showing editing controls when willTransitionToState: is implemented

Tags: uitableview, transition

I'm working on and iOS 7 app..

I've got a very simple custom UITableViewCell (for now, it's just a couple labels) If I over-ride "willTransitionToState:", then the editing controls (delete, re-order) do not appear when I put the tableView in edit mode....the cell shifts the content as expected...

Over-riding didTransitionToState: does not have any effect (shows normal editing controls)

Is there something new in iOS 7.. Do I now need to somehow implement the editing control functionality manually if I over-ride willTransitionToState: ?

Thx !

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent most of the day fighting with various problems with TableViews on iOS 7 :)

I think I managed to recreate your problem. For me, it was fixed by simply calling `super` within the implementation of `willTransitionToState:`  i.e.

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {
    [super willTransitionToState:state];
    NSLog(@"About to transition");
    // Your code here
}
```

Without the call to `[super willTransitionToState:]` the edit control does not seem to appear.

Comment: Important - this method belongs to `UITableViewCell`.